# Andy OS 46.16.819 shared folder missing

Tags: android, shared-folders, emulator

I am (still) using 46.16.819 and suddenly the shared folder "Andy" is missing, i.e. I can't transfer between Andy and my PC, I try create the Andy folder under sdcard\Shared and reboot Andy OS, the file logcat.txt is created under sdcard\Shared\Andy but connection with PC still not establish. Before this happen, I remember that I tried run the andy vm insider vmware player (not success) not sure this will affected Andy OS or not, below please find my Andy.vmx. Currently I need to use Google drive to transfer file. Why not "new" another Andy? Because I've install/config a lot of stuff in existing one and want to keep it. Please advise, thanks.

Regds
LAM Chi-fung

Below is andy.vmx

```
.encoding = "UTF-8"
checkpoint.vmState = ""
cleanShutdown = "FALSE"
config.version = "8"
cpuid.coresPerSocket = "2"
displayName = "andy"
ehci.present = "FALSE"
ethernet0.addressType = "generated"
ethernet0.connectionType = "custom"
ethernet0.generatedAddress = "00:0c:29:b5:aa:bc"
ethernet0.generatedAddressOffset = "0"
ethernet0.pciSlotNumber = "160"
ethernet0.present = "TRUE"
ethernet0.pvnID = "52 1e 82 48 37 00 71 92-e0 0a 90 83 65 0e ad 27"
ethernet0.virtualDev = "vmxnet3"
ethernet0.vnet = "VMnet1"
ethernet0.wakeOnPcktRcv = "FALSE"
ethernet1.address = "00:50:56:18:83:20"
ethernet1.addressType = "static"
ethernet1.connectionType = "custom"
ethernet1.pciSlotNumber = "192"
ethernet1.present = "TRUE"
ethernet1.pvnID = "52 1e 82 48 37 00 71 92-e0 0a 90 83 65 0e ad 27"
ethernet1.virtualDev = "vmxnet3"
ethernet1.vnet = "VMnet8"
ethernet1.wakeOnPcktRcv = "FALSE"
extendedConfigFile = "andy.vmxf"
floppy0.present = "FALSE"
guestOS = "other3xlinux"
guestinfo..Andy.Analytics.InstallerID = ""
guestinfo..Andy.Analytics.InstallerVersion = "46_16_66_C819_C369"
guestinfo..Andy.Analytics.MachineID = "8b8b6500-aa5c-36d6-ab8f-e8e41b83470b"
guestinfo..Andy.Android.Board = "clovertrail"
guestinfo..Andy.Android.Brand = "AndyOS"
guestinfo..Andy.Android.ClearDalvikCacheCommand = "0"
guestinfo..Andy.Android.DPI = "160"
guestinfo..Andy.Android.Device = "AndyWin"
guestinfo..Andy.Android.ID = "3210c74af67b4a14"
guestinfo..Andy.Android.IMEI = "321074674141133"
guestinfo..Andy.Android.Mainkeys = "1"
guestinfo..Andy.Android.Manufacturer = "Andy OS Inc."
guestinfo..Andy.Android.Model = "AndyWin"
guestinfo..Andy.Android.Name = "AndyWin"
guestinfo..Andy.Audio.Transport.Type = "network"
guestinfo..Andy.Host.Language = "zh"
guestinfo..Andy.Host.Region = "HK"
guestinfo..Andy.Host.TimeZone = "Asia/Shanghai"
guestinfo..Andy.Host.Variant = ""
guestinfo..Andy.Info.AffiliationID = ""
guestinfo..Andy.Log.Enabled = "1"
guestinfo..Andy.OpenGL.Connection.RPort = ""
guestinfo..Andy.OpenGL.ScreenHeight = "720"
guestinfo..Andy.OpenGL.ScreenWidth = "1380"
guestinfo..Andy.Playstore.URLs = ""
guestinfo..Andy.Service.Direction = "0"
guestinfo..Andy.Service.Reachability.Enabled = "1"
guestinfo..Andy.Service.Reachability.Timeout = "2000"
gui.exitOnCLIHLT = "FALSE"
hgfs.linkRootShare = "TRUE"
hgfs.mapRootShare = "TRUE"
hpet0.present = "TRUE"
ide0:0.fileName = "android_system_disk.vmdk"
ide0:0.present = "TRUE"
ide0:0.redo = ""
ide0:1.fileName = "android_data_disk.vmdk"
ide0:1.present = "TRUE"
ide0:1.redo = ""
ide1:0.autodetect = "TRUE"
ide1:0.deviceType = "disk"
ide1:0.fileName = "android_flash_disk.vmdk"
ide1:0.present = "TRUE"
ide1:0.redo = ""
ide1:0.startConnected = "TRUE"
ide1:1.present = "FALSE"
isolation.tools.autoInstall.disable = "TRUE"
isolation.tools.copy.disable = "TRUE"
isolation.tools.dnd.disable = "TRUE"
isolation.tools.hgfs.disable = "TRUE"
isolation.tools.paste.disable = "TRUE"
mainMem.useNamedFile = "FALSE"
memTrimRate = "0"
memsize = "1280"
migrate.hostlog = ".\andy-86309368.hlog"
mks.enable3d = "TRUE"
monitor.phys_bits_used = "40"
monitor.virtual_exec = "automatic"
monitor.virtual_mmu = "automatic"
nothing.nothing = "nothing"
numa.autosize.cookie = "20001"
numa.autosize.vcpu.maxPerVirtualNode = "2"
numvcpus = "2"
pciBridge0.pciSlotNumber = "17"
pciBridge0.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge4.functions = "8"
pciBridge4.pciSlotNumber = "21"
pciBridge4.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge4.virtualDev = "pcieRootPort"
pciBridge5.functions = "8"
pciBridge5.pciSlotNumber = "22"
pciBridge5.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge5.virtualDev = "pcieRootPort"
pciBridge6.functions = "8"
pciBridge6.pciSlotNumber = "23"
pciBridge6.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge6.virtualDev = "pcieRootPort"
pciBridge7.functions = "8"
pciBridge7.pciSlotNumber = "24"
pciBridge7.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge7.virtualDev = "pcieRootPort"
powerType.powerOff = "soft"
powerType.powerOn = "soft"
powerType.reset = "soft"
powerType.suspend = "soft"
prefvmx.minVmMemPct = "100"
prefvmx.useRecommendedLockedMemSize = "TRUE"
replay.filename = ""
replay.supported = "FALSE"
sched.mem.pshare.enable = "FALSE"
scsi0.pciSlotNumber = "16"
scsi0.present = "TRUE"
scsi0.virtualDev = "lsilogic"
sharedFolder.maxNum = "1"
sharedFolder0.enabled = "TRUE"
sharedFolder0.expiration = "session"
sharedFolder0.guestName = "Andy"
sharedFolder0.hostPath = "C:\Users\LAM Chi-fung\Andy"
sharedFolder0.present = "TRUE"
sharedFolder0.readAccess = "TRUE"
sharedFolder0.writeAccess = "TRUE"
softPowerOff = "FALSE"
sound.autodetect = "TRUE"
sound.fileName = "-1"
sound.pciSlotNumber = "34"
sound.present = "TRUE"
sound.virtualDev = "hdaudio"
sound.virtualrealcorrection = "10000000000.0"
svga.autodetect = "FALSE"
svga.maxHeight = "1024"
svga.maxWidth = "1280"
svga.vramSize = "16777216"
tools.remindInstall = "FALSE"
tools.syncTime = "TRUE"
tools.upgrade.policy = "manual"
toolsInstallManager.updateCounter = "1"
usb.pciSlotNumber = "-1"
usb.present = "FALSE"
usb:0.deviceType = "hid"
usb:0.parent = "-1"
usb:0.port = "0"
usb:0.present = "TRUE"
usb:1.deviceType = "hub"
usb:1.parent = "-1"
usb:1.port = "1"
usb:1.present = "TRUE"
usb:1.speed = "2"
uuid.action = "create"
uuid.bios = "56 4d 25 e9 c7 90 04 cb-30 e9 c2 7b 6c b5 aa bc"
uuid.location = "56 4d 25 e9 c7 90 04 cb-30 e9 c2 7b 6c b5 aa bc"
vhv.enable = "FALSE"
virtualHW.productCompatibility = "hosted"
virtualHW.version = "10"
vmci0.id = "1270990116"
vmci0.pciSlotNumber = "36"
vmci0.present = "TRUE"
vmotion.checkpointFBSize = "16777216"
vmx.allowNested = "FALSE"
vpmc.enable = "FALSE"
workingDir = "."
guestinfo..Andy.Host.IP = "192.168.52.1"
guestinfo..Andy.Interface.Available = "1"
guestinfo..Andy.OpenGL.Connection.Port = "1323"
guestinfo..Andy.OpenGL.Rotation = "7"
guestinfo..Andy.OpenGL.Stream.ReopenCommand = "0"
guestinfo..Andy.OpenGL.Stream.ReopenCommandResult = "ok"
guestinfo..Andy.Service.Reachability.Endpoint = "vmci://2:1322"
guestinfo..Andy.Service.Reachability.Step = "PLAYER_DONE"
```

Comment: Just as a couple comments... I would make sure you have an "Andy" folder under "C:\Users\LAM Chi-fung\Andy". Also, if you do need to reinstall with the same version, you might think about copying any `.vmdk` files. At a guess, you might be able to use them in a new install (by replacing the default `.vmdk` files). But that is just speculation. =P

Comment: Sure that the Andy folder is in "C:\Users\LAM Chi-fung" and I also suspect the Windows 10 KB4284848 may cause trouble.... ~_~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I solved the problem! I find that there is a file called andy.vmx.bak, just rename to andy.vmx and problem solved.